# progress indicator without dynamic

Tags: notebooks, monitoring

I'm looking for some construction of progress indicator, with chars, numbers, etc... but without use of any Dynamic functions (Monitor and etc...).
The [Any ergonomic tools for the command line kernel?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183632/any-ergonomic-tools-for-the-command-line-kernel) looks pretty, but this is for command line. I'm looking something to use in notebook.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid `Dynamic`?

Comment: @C.E., because of crashing of dynamic updating of notebook, and then I don't know is the process crashed also or only dynamic updating crashed, or both, I have no any feedback. I'm looking for some conservative and robust progress indicator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one approach, based on @b3m2a1's excellent answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145980/36508):

```
Attributes[StaticMonitor] = {HoldAll};
UpdateMonitor[] := Null;
StaticMonitor[expr_, mon_] :=
 Block[
  {UpdateMonitor, boxID = ToString@Unique[]},
  PrintTemporary[RawBoxes@TagBox[ToBoxes@mon, boxID, BoxID -> boxID]];
  UpdateMonitor[] := FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`BoxReferenceReplace[
     FE`BoxReference[
      FE`Evaluate@FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],
      {{boxID}},
      FE`BoxOffset -> {FE`BoxChild[1]}
      ],
     ToBoxes@mon
     ];
  expr
  ]
```

Since we can't rely on `Dynamic` to automatically trigger updates, we need to call `UpdateMonitor[]` to force the update. The actual updating is done by replacing the contents on the cell created by `PrintTemporary` using the `BoxReference*` utilities explained [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133523/36508). One could also replace the entire cell created by `PrintTempoary`, but that leads to undesirable flashing of the scrollbar.

Here is how it looks like in action:

```
StaticMonitor[
 Table[
  Pause@0.1;
  UpdateMonitor[];
  i,
  {i, 10}
  ],
 ProgressIndicator[i, {0, 10}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: where is FrontEnd package gone in M12 ?

Comment: @Dragutin What exactly do you mean? For me, the code works as expected in Mathematica 12.1. (The functions in ``FrontEnd` `` and ``FE` `` are built-in functions/symbols and not really part of any package, so I don't think they can ever be missing, unless they are completely removed at some point)

Answer (score 2):

The folllowing solution is based on some functionalities of https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS_2

In particular, we borrow the `webListenerF` function, the `refresh` function and the `refresh.wl`  file from the JWLS_2 project.
`refresh.wl` is a `StringTemplate` that the `refresh` function uses to create a dynamic HTML page; such HTML page will serve as our monitor/progress indicator.

#### What you need:

1. Download the template from
   https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS_2/blob/master/JWLS_2_kernel/refresh.wl
   and put it in your working directory.
2. Copy the `webListenerF` function definition from line 55 to line 77 of https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS_2/blob/master/JWLS_2.sh
3. Copy the `refresh` function definition from line 139 to 144 of the same `JWLS_2.sh` script above

#### Usage Example

Let's say you have some computation in a loop and you want to monitor the value of a variable `g`:

First of all, activate the socket with `SocketListen[5859, webListenerF]` .
Then create and open the HTML page that monitors the value of `g` with `refresh[HoldForm @ g] // SystemOpen` .

Now you can start your loop process where `g` gets updated, something like

```
Clear[g,k]     
k = {RandomReal[]};

While[True,
      AppendTo[k, RandomReal[]];
      g = ListLinePlot[k, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}];
      Pause@.2]
```

Check your browser and enjoy.

[image]

**Cons**: It works outside the notebook interface.

**Pros**: It works without the notebook interface.

#### Notes:

The `refresh` function takes the page refresh interval **in milliseconds** as a second argument.

For smoother animations, modify the `webListenerF` to export rasters instead of vector graphics. Then add the proper HTML tags in the template.

For maximum efficiency and smoothness, define the whole computation inside `refresh`, so that the kernel executes your code while synchronously serving the javascript client.

If something goes wrong try to close and reopen the socket.